# How to implement the From<T> trait for a custom struct from a 2d array?

Tags: arrays, matrix, rust, traits

I am trying to implement the `From<T>` trait for my custom struct taking a dynamically sized 2-dimensional array of a generic type.

This is my code so far ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4b21fed76a0d5a174dd67b7646f5463f)):

```
pub struct Matrix<K> {
    matrix: Vec<Vec<K>>,
}

impl<K, T, Row> From<T> for Matrix<K>
where
    K: Clone,
    T: AsRef<[Row]>,
    Row: AsRef<[K]>,
{
    fn from(m: T) -> Self {
        Matrix {
            matrix: m
                .as_ref()
                .to_vec()
                .iter()
                .map(|x| x.as_ref().to_vec())
                .collect(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let m = Matrix::from([[1, 2], [3, 4]]);
    println!("{:#?}", m);
}
```

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `Row` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/main.rs:7:12
  |
7 | impl<K, T, Row> From<T> for Matrix<K>
  |            ^^^ unconstrained type parameter
```

When I implement the implement a from() method like in the code block below (so without implementing the `From<T>` trait) the program does work as intended ([playgorund link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=305a509a2180b9e85ac6e07d6f96d081)):

```
pub struct Matrix<K> {
    matrix: Vec<Vec<K>>,
}

impl<K: Clone> Matrix<K> {
    pub fn from<T, Row>(matrix: T) -> Self
    where
        T: AsRef<[Row]>,
        Row: Clone + AsRef<[K]>,
    {
        Matrix {
            matrix: matrix
                .as_ref()
                .to_vec()
                .iter()
                .map(|x| x.as_ref().to_vec())
                .collect(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let m = Matrix::from([[1, 2], [3, 4]]);
    println!("{:#?}", m);
}
```

However i do want to know how to make it work with using the `From<T>` trait since I want my implementation to be similar to how I implemented it for my custom Vector struct ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=827bd3732248c129792a8ca618ec7d26))

```
pub struct Vector<K> {
    vector: Vec<K>,
}

impl<K, T> From<T> for Vector<K>
where
    K: Clone,
    T: AsRef<[K]>,
{
    fn from(v: T) -> Self {
        let v = v.as_ref().to_vec();
        Vector {
            vector: v,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = Vector::from([1, 2]);
    println!("{:#?}", v);
}
```

I know I could use slices but I really want to use the code like this: `let m = Matrix::from([[1, 2], [3, 4]]);` and not like this `let m = Matrix::from(&[&[1, 2], &[3, 4]]);`, so that's why I am using `AsRef<[K]>`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think the problem might be that when you call `Matrix::from::<T>(...)` there could be multiple `Row` types that satisfy the constraints and there would be no way to decide which implementation to use.

Comment: @myrtlecat You are right, but it also makes sense that an imaginary compiler is able to deduce the Row type from T in this case based on the actual parameters. And even if there are still multiple options - provided this list of alternatives in the error. I'm sure there are reasons not to do it. Maybe it is too complicated?

Answer (score 0):

The reason `impl<K, T, Row>` it is not working is due to a compiler limitation.

> Any type parameter of an `impl` must meet at least one of the
> following criteria:
>
> - it appears in the *implementing type* of the impl, e.g. `impl<T> Foo<T>`
> - for a trait impl, it appears in the *implemented trait*, e.g.    `impl<T> SomeTrait<T> for Foo`
> - it is bound as an associated type, e.g. `impl<T, U> SomeTrait for T    where T: AnotherTrait<AssocType=U>`

Long story short, you can't throw in random generic types into impl<...>. Each of the types there has to come from either From<...> list or Matrix<...> list.

I see several potential solutions:

1. Don't use a generic type for the overall data, only for the rows (this is what I ended up trying, see code below).
2. Introduce a Row type into the Matrix list: `Matrix<TElem, TRow>`. Have a `Vec<TRow>` for the data.
3. Same as 2 (`Matrix<TElem, TRow>`), but have an extra `PhantomData<TRow>` and keep `Vec<Vec<TElem>>` for the data.

Both 2 and 3 might limit compatibility between different `Matrix<X>` types.

The simplest solution I've found for (1) is like this:

```
impl<T, K> From<&dyn AsRef<[T]>> for Matrix<K>
where K: Clone, T: AsRef<[K]> + Clone
{
    fn from(m: &dyn AsRef<[T]>) -> Self {
        Self {
            matrix: m.as_ref().iter()
                .map(|row| row.as_ref().to_vec())
                .collect(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let m = Matrix::from(&[[1, 2], [3, 4]] as &dyn AsRef<_>);
    println!("{:#?}", m);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d5cf2ed402f380ecf71bf791b60dec04)

The `as &dyn` clause is unfortunate, but Rust is not smart enough to figure this out. It treats `&[1, 2]` literally as a reference to an array with 2 elements. It feels like it needs to be pushed in order to convert this to a slice which can then become a dyn trait reference.

This ofc can be simplified by a macro, but having a macro makes the whole From idea questionable, because you could instead make a macro that handles the form you want, and constructs a vec! directly such that:

```
matrix!([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

Turns into:

```
Matrix { matrix: vec![vec![1, 2], vec![3, 4]] }
```

Comment: For case 3, you could maintain compatibility by having a `MatrixRows<TElem, TRow>` with a `PhantomData<TRow>` field, and then `impl From<MatrixRows<T, R>> for Matrix<T>` to erase the row type. It's not exactly pretty.